# NodeJS showing different MySQL results after second user session

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, session, express

I'm fairly new with NodeJS and Express, and I got stuck with some probably trivial issue that I can't solve on my own. I've been trying to fix this code myself, but all my efforts were pointless.

Basically I'm looking to make simple web app which supports user logins and shows data related for logged-in user (user profile). And that's what I managed to do on my own. Sort of. After starting up application, "user1" logs-in and data gets displayed for said user, however after logging in as a different user (user2) in other browser, both user sessions show same database results (results got from second user - "user2"). I was about to implement bcrypt for passwords today, but this got me stuck. Here's my code:

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var user = require('./users.model.js');
var data = {}
app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(session({
  secret: 's00p3rc001',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true
}))
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('It works!')
})

app.get('/login', function(req, res, next){
  console.log('SID BEFORE LOGIN: ' + req.session.id)
  res.render('login')
  next();
})

app.post('/login', function(req, res){
  user.checkLoginAndInsertSession(req.body.email, req.body.password, req.session.id, function(result){
    if(result == true){
      req.session.loggedIn = true;
      req.session.uniqueSID = req.session.id;
      user.getBySession(req.session.uniqueSID, function(result){
        data.fromDB = result;
        res.redirect('/profile')
      })
    } else {
      res.send('Failed login!')
    }
  })
})

app.get('/profile', function(req, res){
  if(req.session.loggedIn){
    console.log('SID AFTER LOGIN: ' + req.session.uniqueSID)
    console.log(data.fromDB)
    res.send(data.fromDB)
  }
})
app.listen(3001);
```

**db.js**

```
var config = require('./dbconfig');

module.exports = require('mysql').createPool(config);
```

**dbconfig.js**

```
module.exports = {
  connectionLimit: 10,
  waitForConnections: true,
  acquireTimeout: 30000,
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'dbuser',
  password: 'dbpass',
  database: 'mydb'
}
```

**users.model.js**

```
var db = require('./db');

exports.checkLoginAndInsertSession = function(email, password, session, result){
  db.getConnection(function(err, connection){
    if(err) throw err;
    db.query('SELECT email, password FROM users WHERE email="'+email+'"', function(err, rows){
      if(err) throw err;
      if(email == rows[0].email && password == rows[0].password){
        db.query('UPDATE users SET session="'+session+'" WHERE email="'+rows[0].email+'"', function(err, rows){
          connection.release();
          result(true)
        })
      } else {
        result(false)
      }
    })
  })
}

exports.getBySession = function(session, result){
  db.getConnection(function(err, connection){
    if(err) throw err;
    db.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE session="'+session+'"', function(err, rows){
      connection.release();
      if(err) throw err;
      result(rows);
    })
  })
}
```

**login.ejs**

```
...
<form action="/login" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="email" label="Email:"></input>
  <input type="password" name="password" label="Password:"></input>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" lable="Log in"></input>
</form>
...
```

Here's my table schema

```
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| userid    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| firstname | varchar(45) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| lastname  | varchar(45) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email     | varchar(45) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| password  | varchar(45) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| session   | varchar(45) | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I'd be really grateful if you could point my mistake on here.

Comment: Not to nitpick... but are you storing passwords in the clear on the database? `password == rows[0].password` -- that's a no-no. Save a hash (possibly using at least bcrypt) -- compare `hashUserSent(password) == rows[0].password`

Comment: Currently - yes, but as I stated I was about to implement bcrypt today, but this session problem got me stuck with no progress. This is on my local machine and this is just a learning app.

Comment: Sorry, I skimmed through the question and didn't see it.

Comment: You are not catching this error: `db.query('UPDATE users SET session="'+session+'" WHERE email="'+rows[0].email+'"', function(err, rows){
          connection.release();
          result(true)
        })`
Is the UPDATE really returning success? You should check if there is any error here -- just in case.

Comment: I removed err lines on here, so that my post is shorter, but yeah I have those in my code, no errors whatsoever. I also do DB query in console to check for session data, it's all fine, but data in browser gets messed up.

Comment: You mention that after user2 login  you go back to user1 and see the user2 data, correct? How do you check user1? Do you go directly to "/profile" without any login? You are checking user1 profile using `req.session.uniqueSID`. Is it possible that this variable persists on the server and this value is actually the last one, from user2? Could you check on the server console when trying to see user1 the second time? I think you should try searching the profile by `req.session.id`, not `req.session.uniqueSID` ....

Comment: Here's debug output. http://pastebin.com/EcuA7eHJ 
After user2 login, session field in DB for user1 gets replaced by user2 session.id

Comment: Added a new answer after more thinking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After login, you use `res.redirect('/profile')`. This tells the browser to make a **new** call to the server on the `/profile` route. When that happens, you are serving `data.fromDB`. You expect it to contain data from the previous login -- however, if user 2 logs in between user 1 login and redirection, `data.fromDB` will be updated with user 2's data. At this point, the redirect from user 1 is complete and `data.fromDB` contains user 2's data, not user 1's. This is not necessarily what's happening here, but I would have this in mind and avoid this architecture. I think you should move your `getBySession()` function to the `/profile` route, to make sure that session id is the one queried.

And avoid storing user data on `data.fromDB`, since it is global to the process and might be served incorrectly.

Comment: Hey noderman, thanks for the answer. That's more or less what I actually have done last night before sleep, but I was too tired to update. Here's my final result that's working as it should. http://pastebin.com/hBDa36Fr

Again, thank you for your help!

Comment: Glad to hear that. I am still a bit frustrated with what exactly was wrong on the original code -- the only thing I could see is this global variable getting old data... Cheers.

Comment: For some reason latest login would override session id's in database for all other users with its own. I'm still not sure why though. I have old bugged code on git and I'll test it today / tomorrow with node-inspect. If I manage to pinpoint issue, being that I'm new to NodeJS and JS in general, I'll gladly post an update why original code didn't worked as expected.